# fields_for duplicates during edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1) railscast.

**Controller:** *project_sub_types_controller.rb*

```
def new
    @svn_repos = ['svn_software','svn_hardware']
    @project_sub_type = ProjectSubType.new
    @project_sub_type.repositories.build
end

def edit
  @svn_repos = ['svn_software','svn_hardware']
  @project_sub_type = ProjectSubType.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Model:** *project_sub_type.rb*

```
class ProjectSubType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project_type
  has_many :repositories, :dependent => :destroy

  def repositories_attributes=(repos_attributes)
    repos_attributes.each do |attributes|
      repositories.build(attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

**View:** *_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for @project_sub_type, :html => {:class => 'project_subtype_form'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Project sub type name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <% for repos in @project_sub_type.repositories %>
      <%= fields_for "project_sub_type[repositories_attributes][]", repos do |repos_form| %>
          <% @svn_repos.each do |repos| %>
              <%= repos_form.check_box :repos_name, {}, "#{repos}", nil %>
              <%= h repos -%>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
<%= f.submit "Save"%>
```

This works perfectly during creation of a new record. But Y does the fields_for duplicates during edit. During create I see 2 checkboxes but during edit there are 4 checkboxes which duplicates the other 2 checkboxes. What am I doing wrong?

**Update :** The more times I click on edit and the duplication increases by 1.

Comment: There is way too many loops here. Could you explain what `@project_sub_type.repositories` and `@svn_repos` are?

Comment: @BroiSatse: `@svn_repos = ['svn_software','svn_hardware']` and `@project_sub_type.repositories` is the `ProjectSubType` has many repositories relation. Followed the same way as its given in the rails cast view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% for repos in @project_sub_type.repositories %>
      <%= fields_for "project_sub_type[repositories_attributes][]", repos do |repos_form| %>
          <% @svn_repos.each do |repos| %>
              <%= repos_form.check_box :repos_name, {}, "#{repos}", nil %>
              <%= h repos -%>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Get rid of that and do:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :repositories do |repo_form| %>
    <% @svn_repos.each do |rep| %>
      <%= repo_form.check_box :repos_name, {}, rep, nil %>
      <%= h rep -%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Also get rid of `repositories_attributes=` method in your model and add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :repositories`

The railscast you linked is 7 years old. :)

Comment: I went back to a 7 years link because I tried this and ended up in this problem :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181809/fields-for-for-has-many-association-using-an-array
Even thought I accepted the answer there. I would like the form to automatically build the repository object after submission which is not happening. Can you please help me solve that question. The only difference between you answer and that is `fields_for` I have added `f.fields_for`