# fields_for part not visible in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Controller:** *project_sub_types_controller.rb*

```
def new
    @svn_repos = ['svn_software','svn_hardware']
    @project_sub_type = ProjectSubType.new
end
```

**Model:** *project_sub_type.rb*

```
class ProjectSubType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project_type
  has_many :repositories, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :repositories
end
```

**View:** *_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for @project_sub_type, :html => {:class => 'project_subtype_form'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Project sub type name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :repositories do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.label :select_svn_repositories, "Select SVN repositories" %> 
      <% @svn_repos.each do |repos| %>
          <%= ff.check_box :repos_name, {}, "#{repos}", nil %>
          <%= h repos -%>
      <% end %>
<%= f.submit "Save"%>
```

**Question :** the `fields_for :repositories` part is not displayed in the front end. Can anyone point out what is my mistake? Following : this [link](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/9-nested-model-forms)

Comment: Try adding `@project_sub_type.repositories.build` to your `new` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@project_sub_type` used to create the form doesn't have any associated repositories, therefore there are no nested fields to display on the form.

If you add one (eg. by doing `@project_sub_type.repositories.build` in your controller) then you will see a blank set of fields generated by the `f.fields_for` statement.

Comment: In that case it works, but it creates the object like this: 
`params = "repositories_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"repos_name"=>"svn_hardware"}}}`. It creates an object under `'0'`. Here is my other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181809/fields-for-for-has-many-association-using-an-array . I would like to create the object without 0 so that the object gets created easily. Please answer to that question if you can solve that issue. THanks

Comment: that's exactly how it's supposed to work. So if you were submitting data for multiple repositories at once, they would be nested under "0", "1", etc.

Comment: thats an entirely different question, and there isn't enough information in this question to say.

Comment: @sevenseacat : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181809/fields-for-for-has-many-association-using-an-array for this question can you please help me how to get it nested as '0' , '1' so on ? Currently it is just saving the last selected checkbox .